# Making .exe from .py script

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. Currently, I'm working on project related to civil engineering, where one inputs some values about material, internal forces and such, and then code calculates resistance of ceratin cross section, it's utilization and so on. I have it working in VSCode, but have trouble making it .exe file. Any help is grateful and much appriciated.

I have tried pyinstaller but got nowhere. Once file is compiled, when I run .exe, only thing I got is blank black screen

This is code in question

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Input for calcualation
fy = float(input("Steel yield strength [kN/cm^2] fy = "))
fu = float(input("Steel tensile strenth [kN/cm^2] fu = "))
E = float(input("Steel modulus of elasticity [kN/cm^2] E = "))
NEd = float(input("Compression force [kN] NEd = "))

Lcry = float(input("Buckling length around y (stronger) axis [cm] = "))
Lcrz = float(input("Buckling length around z (weaker) axis [cm] = "))

data = []
with open('HEA.csv', 'r', newline='') as csv_data:

    csv_read = csv.reader(csv_data)
    reader = next(csv_read)
    for row in csv_read:
        name = int(row[0])
        h = float(row[1])
        b = float(row[2])
        tw = float(row[3])
        tf = float(row[4])
        r = float(row[5])
        d = float(row[6])
        A = float(row[7])
        G = float(row[8])
        Iy = float(row[9])
        Wyel = float(row[10])
        Wypl = float(row[11])
        iy = float(row[12])
        Iz = float(row[13])
        Wzel = float(row[14])
        Wzpl = float(row[15])
        iz = float(row[16])
        It = float(row[17])
        Iw = float(row[18])
        data.append([name, h, b, tw, tf, r, d, A, G, Iy, Wyel, Wypl, iy, Iz, Wzel, Wzpl, iz, It, Iw])

data = np.asarray(data)
data = np.transpose(data)

name = data[0]
h = data[1]
b = data[2]
tw = data[3]
tf = data[4]
r = data[5]
d = data[6]
A = data[7]
G = data[8]
Iy = data[9]
Wyel = data[10]
Wypl = data[11]
iy = data[12]
Iz = data[13]
Wzel = data[14]
Wzpl = data[15]
iz = data[16]
It = data[17]


alpy = 0.34

Ncry = ((np.pi**2 * E * Iy)/(Lcry**2))
print(Ncry)

# Nondimensional slednerness

ldy = np.sqrt(((A*fy)/Ncry))

print(ldy)

# auxiliary value

phiy = 0.5*(1+alpy*(ldy-0.2)+ldy**2)

print(phiy)

hiy = 1/(phiy+np.sqrt(phiy**2-ldy**2))

if hiy.all() > 1:
    hiy = 1
hiy = hiy

print(hiy)

NbRd = (hiy*21.24*fy)/1.10

print("Resistance to compression", NbRd)

if NEd/NbRd.all() <= 1:
    print("Resistance is satisfied")
print("Resistance is not satisfied")

ratio = (NEd/NbRd)*100
print(ratio)

plt.plot([name], [ratio], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You should probably describe the tech stack used in the project. I assume there is some kind of UI, so you should, to the bare minimum, say which libraries are you using. Relying on a link is not acceptable (link may go missing in the future and then the question becomes useless to others). For more info, see [here](/help/how-to-ask) and [there](/help/mcve)

Comment: You should edit your question and include the code sample within StackOverflow so question integrity remains if the external link becomes unavailable.

Comment: Have you tried it first with a simple "Hello world" program (without and then with GUI, if any)?

Comment: PyInstaller is pretty common but can be arduous to configure. Show what errors you are  getting from it as well as some of your code and we can potentially problem solve. Some specific packages need manual files added after compilation, such as when you work with Plot.ly's Dash module.

Answer (score 0):

A few points here:

**1- Why are you making it an executable?**

Can't you just distribute the python code for your users? If they're all engineers, that should be easier.

**2- If you absolutely, from the start, need to make it an executable:**

If you absolutely need a software that can run in any machine, maybe python and pyinstaller are not your best friends.

You could make it a web app, that would run on navigators by using something like django.

If it is complex, calculation intensive, but should run fast, maybe you should consider C++.

**3-Bottomline**

Pyinstaller takes a lot of work to actually create an executable, and there are a lot of caveats to be considered when executing it, and creating code that will be bundled by it.

But reading questions here, [the documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html), and particular working with the `--debug=all` option will slowly get your executable in shape.